# Add complex array of objects into another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an source object `obj` that looks like this and an array `input`

```
const obj = {
  name: "xyz",
  filter: {
    and: [
      {
        or: [
          {
            and: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const input = ["test1\name1", "test2\name2"]
```

I need to push objects that are formed after spiltting `input` by `\`. After splitting, using left side of the string i need to form an object like this

`{ type: "type1", value: whatever the left hand value}`

Same for right side value

`{ type: "type2", value: whatever the right hand value}`

And these objects should be pushed to innermost `and` in the source object.

Expected output

```
{
  name: "xyz",
  filter: {
    and: [
      {
        or: [
          {
            and: [
              { type: "type1", value: "test1" },
              { type: "type2", value: "name1" },
              { type: "type1", value: "test2" },
              { type: "type2", value: "name2" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code that I tried

```
function processResult(input) {
  return {
    name: "xyz",
    filter: {
      and: [
        {
          or: [
            {
              and: getUpdatedValues(input)
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
}

// I need the getUpdateValues to be processing the each item from the input array and then sending the two objects back after splitting

function getUpdatedValues(input){
  const updated = input.map(item => {
    const spilt = item.split("\\");
  });
}
```

Comment: `[ or: [ and: ` ---> `[ or: ` this may not be valid javascript. did you mean: `[ { or: ` instead?

Also, the output says `{ type: "type1", value: "type1" },` --- should it actually be: `{ type: "type1", value: "test1" },`. The "left hand side" in the input doesn't have `"type1"` - it does have `"test1"`.

Comment: @jsN00b Typo, corrected it!

Comment: `obj` is invalid, it produces javascript errors.  Expected output is also invalid.

Comment: the `.split()` uses double-slash (double-backslash, to be precise) and this is correct because we need to use one as an escape-character. However, the values in the array do not escape the backslash. This is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the input array would include an escape character and could be like so: `["test1\\name1", "test2\\name2"]`, presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const transformMyArr = (myArr) => (
  myArr.flatMap(
    s => {
      const [leftie, rightie] = s.split('\\');
      return ([{
        type: 'type1', value: leftie
      }, {
        type: 'type2', value: rightie
      }]);
    }
  )
);

/* code explanation
// method to transform the array to required format
const transformMyArr = (myArr) => (
  myArr.flatMap(  // iterate over the array and remove nested-array in result
    s => {        // manipulate each array element
      // "split" using "\\" and store the left-side as "type"
      // and the rest as "value"
      const [type, value] = s.split('\\');
      // explicit return of an array with two objects per array elt
      return ([{
        type: 'type1', value: leftie
      }, {
        type: 'type2', value: rightie
      }]);
    }
  )         // implicit return from the "transformMyArr" method
);

*/

let myInputArr = ["test1\\name1", "test2\\name2"];

const myObj = {
  name: "test",
  filter: {
    and: [{
      or: [{
        and: [...transformMyArr(myInputArr) ]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

console.log('updated obj:\n', myObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

**EDIT**

> the left and right side value after splitting can be present in different items in the array too. How can I have only unique type1 , type2 objects inside final array

```js
const myTransform2 = arr => {
  // set-up empty arrays to hold left & right side elements
  let leftEltArr = [], rightEltArr = [];
  // iterate over the arg-array using ".forEach()"
  arr?.forEach(
    s => {
      // split using "\\" to store left & right side elts
      const [leftElt, rightElt] = s.split('\\');
      // push elements into respective arrays
      leftEltArr.push(leftElt);
      rightEltArr.push(rightElt);
    }
  );
  // return the result using left & right arrays
  return (
    ([...new Set(leftEltArr)])      // remove dupes
    .map(value => ({ type: 'type1', value }))   // transform to required format
    .concat(              // concat result of similar operation on right-side
      ([...new Set(rightEltArr)])
      .map(value => ({ type: 'type2', value }))
    )
  );
};

// updated sample input with 3rd elt which has duplicates
// on both left-side & right-side of the "\\"
let myInputArr = ["test1\\name1", "test2\\name2", "test1\\name2"];

const myObj = {
  name: "test",
  filter: {
    and: [{
      or: [{
        and: [...myTransform2(myInputArr) ]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

console.log('transformed object:\n', myObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: there should be four objects inside of innermost and

Comment: `{ type: "type1", value: "test1" }, { type: "type2", value: "name1" }, { type: "type1", value: "test2" }, { type: "type2", value: "name2" }`

Comment: Each entry of the `input` array should return two objects.

Comment: yeah, i messed up on the last one. This ought to work.

Comment: thanks one more additon. the left and right side value after splitting can be present in different items in the array too. How can I have only unique `type1` , `type2` objects inside final array

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it.  It's tricky because the input structure is so different to the output, and there is no reference for "type1"/"type2" other than the array element position.

```js
const input = ["test1\\name1", "test2\\name2"];

function processResult(input) {
  return {
    name: "xyz",
    filter: {
      and: [
        {
          or: [
            {
              and: getUpdatedValues(input)
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
}

function getUpdatedValues(input){
  return input.flatMap((item, i) => item.split("\\").map(val => ({[`type${i + 1}`]: val })));
}

console.log(processResult(input));
```